# why does floating a div stop list link elements from floating

Tags: css

if I set `#nav li a` to `float:left`then it displays the list horizontally

but then if i do `#nav{ float:right;}` the list floats to the right but displays vertically

if I use just `#nav li { float:left}`it works fine but why does the floating change when using the `a`selected?

```
<div id="header">


        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ccc</a></li>

        </ul>



</div>
```

css

```
#header{
width:600px;
height:160px;
background-color:#DDD;
border-top: solid 1px #DDD; 

}

#nav {
list-style: none;
float: right; 
}

#nav li{
float:left; /* if I have the "float:left" here it will always display horizontally
}


#nav li a{
             /*if I float:left here instead of in "#nav li" it only works if "#nav" isn't floated
padding: 10px;
background-color: #888;
color:222;
text-decoration: none;

}
```

Comment: Because when you set `#nav{float:right;}` you're taking it out of the document flow, and the floated element will take as little width as possible. Give the `#nav` a fixed width

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: i dont think you can align it horizontally using simply `#nav li a{float:left}`. May be you have some other CSS. Show your HTML and respective CSS

Comment: It might be width problem. So increase the width of #nav

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic thats works but why does floating the #nav li elements not take them out of the document flow ie. it works without a fixed width if I float #nav li?

Comment: @Tommy `ul` is a block element  that by default takes up 100% width, but when you float the `#nav` it doesn't know how wide it should be, it will be wide as the widest child element. If you had another `ul#nav2` that was floated, it would align next to the `#nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `#nav li a { float:left; }` only, the `a` element will float inside `li` and stay vertically above each other.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kdR/)

But if you also add `#nav li { list-style-type: none; }` the list elements will collapse, because there's no content anymore and then the `a` tags will appear horizontally.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kdR/1/)

Now, if you do `#nav { float:right; }`, the `a`s will appear vertically stacked, because `nav` occupies just the width necessary.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kdR/2/)

If you use `#nav li { float:left; }` instead from the beginning, the links will appear horizontally no matter what. Because now, it's not the `a` inside `li`, but the `li` inside `ul` floating to the left.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2kdR/3/)

Answer (score 1):

> if I set `#nav li a` to `float:left`then it displays the list horizontally

Not if that’s the only thing you are doing in a `ul > li > a` structure.

> if I use just `#nav li { float:left}`it works fine but why does the floating change when using the `a`selected?

If you just float the `a` elements, then the list items still behave as block, and therefor take a line each. If you float the `li` instead, then they align next to each other.